# What can cause an application to behave differently when started as bundle vs. executable?

Tags: macos, performance, development

I have a C++ application that is built as a bundle (.app) for macOS, using clang (from Xcode) and CMake. This application behaves differently when double-clicked in the Finder, as when started directly using the embedded executable from the terminal (/path/to/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp).

In general, the app works exactly the same, but some features are 50x-100x slower as bundle vs. as executable. For instance, one takes 10 minutes instead of a few seconds.

The Info.plist file in the bundle does not contain anything special.

What are the differences between starting bundle and executable, that could explain this different behavior?

This question is different than [MacOS, differences between running a bundled app and running the bundle's executable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118598/macos-differences-between-running-a-bundled-app-and-running-the-bundles-execut) since the later is a general question about the differences in theory, while here it is about an observed difference in practice, that needs an explanation.

Comment: You could try to run it in Instruments. If it's slow there as well you can see _where_/_what_ is slow. That may give a hint to how to solve this.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this if you could be more specific. Exactly what are those "very specific operations"? - Can you include the source code for that part perhaps?

Comment: I cannot share the source code unfortunately. By "very specific operations" I mean a specific feature of the application that executes normal C++ code. That code stresses maybe the heap and/or the stack, however it runs fine when started as executable.

Comment: Using Instruments is a good idea, I will try out, however the debug symbols are stripped, so I am not sure how much information that will give.

Comment: If you run in terminal it will use the environment of your shell - If GUI then a different env

Comment: `tccd` can pose challenges to non-codesigned bundles while performing actions like starting a child process.

Comment: Great post! Linking to a canonical question helps everyone. If you want to edit the target to contain your details, please do so. If you want to edit this to make it different than the linked one we can reverse the link…

Comment: Currently this question is just as general as the duplicate. If there are observed differences we need to see the differences. Ideally we need to reproduce it on our machines to able to say what is happening