# While using bash on macOS, why is it necessary to use the "open" command to launch the firefox application?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, bash, firefox

I am new to macOS. Also, I am using Apple Macbook Air M1 Monterey 12.5.

Before buying this Mac, I was using Linux (NixOS and Ubuntu) for several years. In Linux, while using `bash`, I was able to open firefox just by doing:

`$ firefox`

macOS also comes from the Unix family and I am using `bash` on both OS. Thus, I do **not** understand why I can't do:

```
Pedros-MacBook-Air:~ pedro$ firefox
-bash: firefox: command not found
```

To open firefox from terminal, I need to do the command below to open firefox on Mac:

`Pedros-MacBook-Air:~ pedro$ open -a firefox`

To make things even more obscure, to open emacs I can simply do the following and it works:

`Pedros-MacBook-Air:~ pedro$ emacs`

Why is it so? Why I can't open firefox in bash's macOS as I used to do in Linux distros' bash? And why can I open emacs this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacOS, differences between running a bundled app and running the bundle's executable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118598/macos-differences-between-running-a-bundled-app-and-running-the-bundles-execut)

Comment: @SolarMike Don't see the duplicate. The question here is about the difference between a binary in /usr/bin and an application in /Applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run MacOS bundled programs like Firefox from the terminal using *open*.
Or you can run the executable within the program bundle by executing it from its path:
*/Application/FireFox.app/Contents/MacOS/FireFox*.

Standard I/O apps in the binaries path of your shell can be executed by the name of their executable.

Or you actually execute a shell script which opens the binary - bundled app or its executable. If you e.g. installed some program you downloaded, what exactly is done when you execute a command in your shell depends on the programm.

Similar you can wrap shell scripts or standard i/O programs into a bundle using e.g. [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

Self-contained bundled programs facilitate their installation and deinstallation by allowing to do this using drag&drop in the Finder.

Comment: just saw that [this was already answered previously here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118598/macos-differences-between-running-a-bundled-app-and-running-the-bundles-execut).

Comment: @WGroleau, what about emacs? Shouldn't it be considered a GUI?

Comment: this should be a new question. you should provide in detail what exactly you want to use Emacs for.

Comment: If /Application/FireFox.app/Contents/MacOS was in your $path, then firefox would work. But almost any app that has a GUI is in a *.app wrapper like the one mentioned here.

Comment: Doesn't emacs use `curses` to position characters in a terminal?  One might consider that a GUI but that's not the way most people use the term.  An executable CAN has a GUI without a .app package but most well-known MacOS apps are packaged.

Comment: @WGroleau Emacs can either run in the terminal or fully graphical. The one provided with macOS is terminal only and not a bundled app